# Hierarchical select module issue in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy

i am using 'Hierarchical select' module in Drupal to create 2 drop down of States and cities and connecting the city ones to state in a way by changing the state,the list of cities changes too.(it is beside of CCK and taxonomy content module)

The problem is that by selecting the state and city for a new content,just the city shown.but i need both of them,State - city combination.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical select is UI representation of hierarchical structure of vocabulary that is normally shown in a flat list.

From a single vocabulary (if multi select is disabled) you can select only one term. Selecting a leaf would not enlist parent tids.

Use `taxonomy_get_parents()` or `taxonomy_get_parents_all()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all that data inside of one vocabulary and cities are children of states, once you select a city, it should display `State >> City` on the node. if you're displaying them with $terms; then it should display in such fashion.